# Swap elements in two arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, swap

Say I have these two lists (could be of different sizes):

```
const a = [0,1,3];
const b = [7,2,6,4];
```

say I want to *swap* element `1` of `a`, with element `3` of `b`?
what's the easiest way to do this?

AKA, I am looking to do this:

```
swap(1, a, 3, b) => { a: [0,4,3], b: [7,2,6,1] }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap two elements between two arrays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71505334/swap-two-elements-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function swap(i, a, j, b) {
  const t = a[i]
  a[i] = b[j]
  b[j] = t
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want a one liner

```js
const swap = (p1, a1, p2, a2) => [a1[p1],a2[p2]] = [a2[p2], a1[p1]];

const a = [0,1,3];
const b = [7,2,6,4];
swap(1, a, 3, b)
console.log(a, b);
```